# How should I install hardwood flooring around spindles?

Tags: hardwood-floor, railing, engineered-flooring

I have oak steps that we installed up to a living room that is carpeted.  How do I install hardwood floors and deal with the spindles on the floor?  My husband made adjustments when he did the stairs (because of the angle, etc) but we are unsure how to tackle the hardwood install on the rest of the spindles across the floor when we remove the carpet..

Comment: I'm really going to need a picture here.  Can you upload one somewhere and post a link?  One of us will edit it into the original question.

Comment: Agreed it's not really clear what the issue is.. Though I think the answer might be to remove the banister spindles, put the floor down and then reinstall...

Comment: My guess is that the living room, currently carpeted, has a descending staircase protected by a railing to stop people from falling down the hole.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation and I know that you are saying the spindles are attached to the floor. I would get some hardwood and cut out like the tooth pattern around the spindles - this will give you a clean edge to line up on.  Remember to make a template of the exact space, then cut out on your wood and slip in. Allow the complete depth of the spindle on the one piece of wood - then you just have to put a straight strip up against it.   In my case, to take down 60 some spindles is not an option. I will be using 6 to 8 foot length to cut these out in.  I am using heavy brown paper as my template or light cardboard (Bristol).